# Minecraft doesn't save progress

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My issue is that when I load the game (state A) and play for a while (state B), then save and exit, and load again, the game is at state A, rather than state B, i.e. it did not save the progress I made.

For example: I'm in my house with three gold ingots in my inventory. Then I'll play for another half hour. At the end of the half hour, i will have three gold ingots in my inventory plus two diamonds. I'll then save and quit to title but when i log in I'll be back in my house with only three gold ingots in my inventory.

This also happens on newly created worlds. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I assume this is in Single Player. What did you do between the last time saving actually worked up until the time it first didn't work anymore? It might be that your permissions for the save folder are somewhat broken.

Comment: i downloaded a new texture pack. would that affect it?

Comment: Do you still have it installed? If so, What did you do exactly? Did you change any permissions on the folder? Can you remove the texture pack and try again?

Comment: yes i do still have it installed. I'm on a mac, so i just went into my library, then application support, then minecraft, then resource packs and dragged it in and it showed up in the game. im sorry, i dont know what you mean by permissions

Comment: The way it looks your minecraft can't write changes to the world back into the save file. Usually the cause for something like that is that the application does not have permissions to write that folder. Did you try to create a new world and change something there?

Comment: yes its happened in about three different worlds i tried. and they have all been after i downloaded the texture pack.

Comment: Try this: With minecraft closed, back up your .minecraft folder (copy it somewhere save), then remove it. Start your minecraft executable, and let the launcher download the game again. This will create the .minecraft folder again. Now try create a new world and see if the problem persists. If it does not you can compare permissions of the backup worlds and the new worlds, and if they are the same, copy them over.

Comment: sorry im really not good with computers. but when you say back it up do you mean onto a usb or something?

Comment: Well, it does not have to be USB. I don't know how folders are called in MacOS, but you can copy it where you keep your personal documents for example. Some location where the files will not be deleted immediately.

Comment: ok thx ill try that

Comment: i tried logging out and in a few times and its working great. thanks private_meta

Comment: @private_meta Seeing that it worked, you should post that as an answer for posterity's sake

Comment: I posted the combined comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The way it looks your minecraft can't write changes to the world back into the save file. Usually the cause for something like that is that the application does not have permissions to write that folder. Did you try to create a new world and change something there?

Try this: With minecraft closed, back up your .minecraft folder (copy it somewhere save), then remove it. Start your minecraft executable, and let the launcher download the game again. This will create the .minecraft folder again. Now try create a new world and see if the problem persists. If it does not you can compare permissions of the backup worlds and the new worlds, and if they are the same, copy them over.

It does not have to be USB. I don't know how folders are called in MacOS, but you can copy it where you keep your personal documents for example. Some location where the files will not be deleted immediately.