# Unable to collect cobblestone after a while

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing this world for a while now and I have been able to collect cobblestone just fine, but suddenly whenever I destroy a block, it's not going into my inventory. I have tried a wooden, stone and iron pickaxe, but none of them have worked. I have closed the program down and started it up again, and it let me play normally for about 10 minutes, but then started again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: does the block break instantly?

Comment: No. it does it completely normally. it even breaks faster when i use a better pickaxe. The stones just not going into my inventory.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a stupid question, but is your inventory full?

Comment: no. ive even got spaces in my toolbar.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't just seeing stacks? Keep in mind materials like stone can stack up to 64 blocks per stack.

Comment: no. there's no stone in my inventory or toolbar at all.

Comment: Turn your volume way up. if you hear a "pip" you are picking the item up, it is just going somewhere

Comment: nope. i dont hear any pip

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Are you playing a local game or on a server? Are you in creative, survival, or adventure mode? Does this happen in other worlds?

Comment: no mods. local game. survival. and this is the only world ive been playing since this started

Comment: very interesting... Have you tried going into other worlds? its possible that world is just corrupted.

Comment: Do you see any item drop when the stone is broken? Does the stone crack as you mine it or just disappear instantly? Does this happen with any other types of blocks?

Comment: it happens with every block ive tried. wood, stone, iron. and yea they do crack but nothings on the ground or inventory. ill try creating a new world and see what happens

Comment: ok it appears my computer is completely broken cause when i tried to create a new world its stuck at the loading screen and wont let me shut minecraft with the close button

Comment: Try restarting your Computer

Comment: it says minecraft cancelled the restart. ill try holding down my power button

Comment: This may be the cause of your other issue in your previous [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173553/when-i-log-in-to-minecraft-it-brings-me-back-in-a-different-spot-then-when-i-sa)

Comment: ok so in the new world its letting me collect stuff but it did it in the old world for a little bit then randomly stopped. ill give a few minutes and see if the problem starts again

Comment: `/gamerule doTileDrops false`?

Comment: nah its just stopped letting me pick up blocks again

Comment: Do datepiccoderguywhoprograms suggestion

Comment: Instead of false put true

Comment: do i just type that into my chat bar?

Comment: Yes /gamerule doTileDrops true

Comment: yea its letting me collect blocks normally. thank you, guys.

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the exstensive discussion in the comments, it has appeared as though you had `doTileDrops` set to `false`. Change this by entering in `/gamerule doTileDrops true`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you mine stone with a pickaxe you will get cobblestone. If you mine stone with a silk touch enchanted pickaxe, you will get stone.

Try clearing out you entire inventory except for a pickaxe, go mine some stone and see what you get, if you get cobblestone then that's normal. If you get nothing THEN there's an issue. In order to get stone it can either be created in a furnace or mined using a silk touch enchanted pickaxe.

EDIT:
Try
1. `Creating a new world`
2. `Restarting your computer`
3. `Send the command /gamerule doTileDrops true`

Comment: oh sorry i mean no cobblestone is entering my inventory. im not using a silk enchanted pickaxe.

Comment: Is it stacking up, is it not even dropping after you mine the block, what does it do when you mine it.

Comment: when i mine it, the blocks cracking and breaking but nothings appearing on the ground or in my inventory. also i tried to dump everything in my chest and mine some stone with just my pickaxe in my inventory but found out that its not letting me access my chest or anything. its just letting me break stuff and not collect anything. so, the issues might be related or something

Comment: Try what Travis said, try mining a different block and see what happens...